# Duplicate Classes on adding Firestore

Tags: java, android, firebase, gradle, google-cloud-firestore

Recently Added Firebase-Firestore to my android project and while building started getting Duplicate references to classes in the protobuf.

`build.gradle`

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all
// sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    ext.protobufVersion = '0.8.6'

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        maven { url "https://jcenter.bintray.com" }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.31.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.41"
        classpath 'com.akaita.android:easylauncher:1.3.1'
        classpath "com.google.protobuf:protobuf-gradle-plugin:$protobufVersion"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'com.akaita.android.easylauncher'
apply plugin: 'com.google.protobuf'

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

configurations {
    playstoreImplementation
    compatImplementation
    freeCompatImplementation
    stagingCompatImplementation
}

ext {
    supportLibVersion = '28.0.0'
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta2'
    /*playstoreImplementation('com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.2') {
            exclude group: 'com.google.firebase', module: 'firebase-core'
        }*/
    compatImplementation 'androidx.emoji:emoji-appcompat:1.0.0'
    freeCompatImplementation 'androidx.emoji:emoji-bundled:1.0.0'
    stagingCompatImplementation 'androidx.emoji:emoji-bundled:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'org.sufficientlysecure:openpgp-api:10.0'
    implementation 'com.github.inputmice:Android-Image-Cropper:2.7.2'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v13:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-rc01'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.emoji:emoji:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha07'
    implementation 'org.bouncycastle:bcmail-jdk15on:1.58'
    implementation 'org.whispersystems:signal-protocol-java:2.6.2'
    implementation 'org.conscrypt:conscrypt-android:1.3.0'

    implementation 'rocks.xmpp:xmpp-addr:0.8.0'
    implementation 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-android:6.0.1'
    implementation 'de.measite.minidns:minidns-hla:0.2.4'
    implementation 'me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.22@aar'
    implementation 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.wefika:flowlayout:0.4.1'
    implementation 'net.ypresto.androidtranscoder:android-transcoder:0.2.0'

    implementation 'org.hsluv:hsluv:0.2'
    //Butterknife dependency
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.2.0'
    kapt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.2.0'
    //Network Retrofit and okhttp
    implementation('com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0') {
        // exclude Retrofit’s OkHttp dependency module and define your own module import
        exclude module: 'okhttp'
    }
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.hbb20:ccp:2.2.3'
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1'
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:answers:1.4.7'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:19.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-dynamic-links:19.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.3.1'
    implementation 'com.wdullaer:swipeactionadapter:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:3.2.0'
    implementation 'io.michaelrocks:libphonenumber-android:8.10.1'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    implementation 'ch.halcyon:squareprogressbar:1.6.4'
    implementation 'com.github.zawadz88:material-activity-chooser:0.2.2'
    implementation 'com.urbanairship.android:urbanairship-fcm:11.0.1'
    implementation 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.12'
    implementation 'com.github.kal72:RackMonthPicker:1.6.0'
    implementation "android.arch.work:work-runtime:1.0.0-alpha11"
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.9'
    implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.play:core:1.6.4'
    implementation 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1'


    //What's new library
    implementation('io.github.tonnyl:whatsnew:0.1.2') {
        exclude module: 'annotations'
    }

    //Showcase view library
    implementation 'com.github.amlcurran.showcaseview:library:5.4.3'

    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:2.0.0'
    implementation files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
    //firebase analytics
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.0'

    //https://jitpack.io/p/kapilmhr/AlphabetIndexFastScrollRecyclerview
    implementation 'com.github.kapilmhr:AlphabetIndexFastScrollRecyclerview:1.0.0'

}

ext {
    travisBuild = System.getenv("TRAVIS") == "true"
    preDexEnabled = System.getProperty("pre-dex", "true")
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    signingConfigs {
        company{
            {...}
        }
    }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 120
        versionName "2.10.3"
        archivesBaseName += "-$versionName"
        applicationId "com.company.chat"
        resValue "string", "applicationId", applicationId
        resValue "string", "app_name", "Company"
        multiDexEnabled true
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }
    }

    dataBinding {
        enabled true
    }

    dexOptions {
        // Skip pre-dexing when running on Travis CI or when disabled via -Dpre-dex=false.
        preDexLibraries = preDexEnabled && !travisBuild
        jumboMode true
        javaMaxHeapSize "2g"

    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    flavorDimensions("distribution", "emoji")

    productFlavors {
        /*playstore {
            dimension "distribution"
            versionNameSuffix "+p"
        }*/
        free {
            dimension "distribution"
            {...}

        }
        staging {
            dimension "distribution"
            {...}

        system {
            dimension "emoji"
            versionNameSuffix "s"
        }
        compat {
            dimension "emoji"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            //versionNameSuffix "r"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.company
            zipAlignEnabled true


        }
        debug {

            applicationIdSuffix ".dev"
            shrinkResources false
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        disable 'MissingTranslation', 'InvalidPackage', 'MissingQuantity', 'AppCompatResource'
    }

    subprojects {

        afterEvaluate {
            if (getPlugins().hasPlugin('android') ||
                    getPlugins().hasPlugin('android-library')) {

                configure(android.lintOptions) {
                    disable 'AndroidGradlePluginVersion', 'MissingTranslation'
                }
            }

        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/BCKEY.DSA'
        exclude 'META-INF/BCKEY.SF'
    }

    // https://proandroiddev.com/how-to-setup-your-android-app-to-use-protobuf-96132340de5c
    // Added to fix duplicate classes issue
    protobuf {
        protoc {
            // You still need protoc like in the non-Android case
            artifact = 'com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.0.0'
        }
        plugins {
            javalite {
                // The codegen for lite comes as a separate artifact
                artifact = 'com.google.protobuf:protoc-gen-javalite:3.0.0'
            }
        }
        generateProtoTasks {
            all().each { task ->
                task.builtins {
                    // In most cases you don't need the full Java output
                    // if you use the lite output.
                    remove java
                }
                task.plugins {
                    javalite { }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    sourceSets{
        main.java.srcDirs += "${protobuf.generatedFilesBaseDir}/main/javalite"
    }
}
```

To fix the error I followed the resolutions [here](https://proandroiddev.com/how-to-setup-your-android-app-to-use-protobuf-96132340de5c) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57019439/duplicate-class-in-protobuf-lite-and-protobuf-java), I continue getting the below errors in protobuf.

```
Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessageLite found in modules protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:2.5.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1) 
Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessageLite$Builder found in modules protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:2.5.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessageLite$Builder$LimitedInputStream found in modules protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:2.5.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1) 
Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser found in modules protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:2.5.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar) com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ByteString found in modules protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:2.5.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ByteString$1 found in modules protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:2.5.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ByteString$ByteIterator found in modules protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:2.5.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1) 
Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ByteString$CodedBuilder found in modules protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:2.5.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ByteString$Output found in modules protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:2.5.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.CodedInputStream found in modules protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:2.5.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.CodedOutputStream found in modules protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:2.5.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.CodedOutputStream$OutOfSpaceException found in modules protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:2.5.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1) ...
Go to the documentation to learn how to Fix dependency resolution errors.
```

Comment: Me also stuck with exact problem. Tried following code. But face crash issue 

implementation('org.whispersystems:signal-protocol-java:2.6.2') { exclude module: 'protobuf-java' } implementation('com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.3.1') { exclude module: 'protobuf-lite' } implementation 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1'

Comment: I will offer a 200 bounty for your solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a fix generate the gradle dependency tree using `gradle dependencies` command, This tree will show you from where are you getting `protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar` and then simply exclude this jar using exclude pattern in gradle like this -

```
dependencies {
  compile('com.example.m:m:1.0') {
     exclude group: 'org.unwanted', module: 'x 
  }
}
```

Comment: this does not fix the issue above. If the above has worked for you can list out detailed steps for the same? Kept getting the earlier error

Comment: implementation('org.whispersystems:signal-protocol-java:2.6.2') {
        exclude group: 'com.google.protobuf', module: 'protobuf-java:2.5.0'
    } did this, does not work

Comment: Part of this answer helped me fix the issue. implementation('org.whispersystems:signal-protocol-java:2.6.2') {
        exclude module: 'protobuf-java'
    } implementation('com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.3.1') {
        exclude module: 'protobuf-lite'
    }  implementation 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1'

Comment: @ichthyocentaurs can you share your solution? I tried this. It compiled but got crash from whispersystems:signal library.

Comment: are you using both whispersystems:signal-protocol and firebase? We have since moved away from whispersystems library. but can surely help share the details with you from that time

Comment: Just an anology example here
we use both retrofit and okhttp libs and retrofit in itself also uses okhttp so we did this
implementation('com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0') {
        // exclude Retrofit’s OkHttp dependency module and define your own module
        exclude module: 'okhttp'
    }
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.1'

Comment: @ichthyocentaurs yes we're using both libraries. Yes tried to exclude module. But no luck. still duplicate issue happens.

Comment: are you able to share your build.gradle in a separate questions? and share the link